# Jenkins pipeline running bash in Windows

Tags: git, docker, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I have installed jenkins on my local computer and I want to create a pipeline. But expectedly I can't run bash scripts.Git, Docker and kubectl has been installed in my local PC, so I can run these codes normally through vsCode terminal. What kind of fix should I do, should I move the whole setup to linux?

I'm new please don't be too hard on me :).

```
pipeline {

  environment {
    workDir = "C:\\xxx"
  }
  agent any

  stages {

    stage('change directory') {
      steps {
        sh 'cd $workDir'
      }
    }

    stage('Checkout Source') {
      steps {
        sh 'git reset --hard origin/master'
      }
    }

    stage('Build image') {
      steps{
        script {
          sh 'docker build -t xxx:latest .' 
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Pushing Image') {
      environment {
               registryCredential = 'dockerhublogin'
           }
      steps{
        script {
          sh 'docker push -t xxx:latest ' 
          }
        }
      }
    

    stage('Deploying App to Kubernetes') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh 'kubectl create -f xxx-deploy.yaml'
        }
      }
    }

    stage('Service app to Kubernetes') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh 'kubectl create -f xxx-svc.yaml'
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: If you are on Windows then I think cmd will work for you. If not then install a plugin for bash in Jenkins and write a script of your commands.

Comment: To change directory for subsequent steps, use [dir](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#dir-change-current-directory)

Answer (score 0):

The plugin [**Pipeline: Nodes and Processes**](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/) you're using to call `sh` also includes [`bat` for Windows batch scripts](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script) that you can use as an alternative. So you can try with:

```java
stage('change directory') {
  steps {
    bat 'cd $workDir'
  }
}
```